RateLimitError: Error code: 429, chatgpt api not working
I want to use the ChatGPT API for a project. I had an older account with $18 in free credit. However, it expired, and I created a new account where I got $5 in free credit. But still, when I request something from the API, it shows as follows:

RateLimitError: Error code: 429 - {'error': {'message': 'You exceeded
your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For
more information on this error, read the docs:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.',
'type': 'insufficient_quota', 'param': None, 'code':
'insufficient_quota'}}

I need to have a working API workflow within today, but it doesn't work at all, and I am depressed!
Here is the code:
import openai
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI(api_key= "{the api key}")

response = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "user", "content": "What is the current population of the world?"}
  ]
)
print(response)


If you need to have a working API workflow within today, I would recommend adding actual paid credit to your OpenAI account. See the documentation about usage quotas of various tiers.

The error message tells you what to do. Just read it and act accordingly.

See the OpenAI documentation about the request quotas of various account tiers. Even if you might have credit left, you're still beholden to those quotas.
At the time of writing, gpt-3.5-turbo API requests are limited to 3 requests per minute and 200 requests per day for free tiers, which isn't much at all.
Simply adding $5 of credit will upgrade you to Tier 1, where you get 3,500 requests per minute and 10,000 requests per day.
If you need to have a working API workflow within today (and cure your depression that way), I would suggest doing that.
